# Spotlight not working with Netgear ReadyNAS

Tags: spotlight, nas

I am unable to search AFP shares on a netgear NAS device using spotlight. Spotlight reverts to the default local hard drive. "Shared" is not user selectable. The NAS is using the latest Netgear OS V6. The unit is new and installed 10/2016.
Can Spotlight be used to search NAS shares, or is there another application that will resolve this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into this Netgear KB article https://kb.netgear.com/000045492/ReadyNAS-OS-6-8-File-Search

> #### Enabling File Search
>
> To enable File Search on your ReadyNAS,
>
> 1. Click System > Settings.
> 2. Under Services, click File Search.
> 3. Check the Enabled box, then click Apply.
>
> File Search can also be enabled from the System > Overview screen.

> #### File Search via Finder on macOS
>
> If you use macOS, File Search integrates with Spotlight on SMB and AFP connections to ReadyNAS shares. If your share is set to be indexed and is mounted on your macOS, Spotlight will not have to use additional resources to scan the share. NETGEAR recommends using SMB instead of AFP and enabling .